# How to get a reference to parent context of an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using entity framework in a project and we are trying to access other tables that are not linked to the table directly. Those tables are mostly config tables with default values. I know we can simple create a new Entities "context" using something like this :

```
DAL.Models.MSSQL.GestionProjets.GestionProjets_DEVEntities entities = new DAL.Models.MSSQL.GestionProjets.GestionProjets_DEVEntities();
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible (and most likely more efficient) way to do it, something like myProjet.ParentEntities (or some other properties).

I can't seem to find anything on this.

Edit : It seems that my question may not be really clear. Suppose I got the following tables :

```
Client (Id,Name,Address,SendMail)
Contact (Id,IdClient,Name,etc...)
DefaultConfig  (DefaultSendMail,etc...)
```

In this case, clients and contact are linked by the FK, so I could easily do
    Client cl = GetMyClientInSomeWay(0;
    List contacts = cl.Contact;

or
    Contact co = GetMyContactInSomeWay();
    Client cl = co.Client;

but in no way I could do something like this
    Client cl = GetMyClientInSomeWay();
    cl.SendMail = cl.DefaultConfig.SendMail;

which is what I want to acheive in the end. I know I could find some way when I am working with already initialiased DBContext (in the UI for example) and do something lile
    cl.SendMail = EntitiesContext.DefaultConfig.First().SendMail;

or something like that, but when I am in the object itself (for example, in a partial class that extend my entity fonctionality), I can't do this, or at least I don't know how to.

Thanks.

Comment: Like a linq query?

Comment: Why not create the entity in a c# class, configure a repository pattern with dependecy injection(simple injector) and access all the tables with linq?

Comment: @LightWalker, I don't really understand what you mean, got any example ?

Comment: What I mean is that I would like to be able to access the config table info from virtually any other object. I don't have any foreing key to those table because they don't require any, but I still have to access those.

Comment: for example you have object A and objectB but you want objectC in both? Or are you saying you need someway to access it with code in a class? If there isn't a foreign key you can't reference one object, if you have a list of objectC in each class that contains all rows in the table is not very effective. If you have one object and later populate it in code with watch you want is more effective.

Comment: For the code approach I would configure a repository pattern with dependency injection and have something like  "IRepository ObjectARepository {get; set}" same for objectB, and then access it with linq like var query= from A in ObjectARepository.GetAll() from B in ObjectBRepository.GetAll().Where(X => X.property = A.Property) select B; or use separate objects to accomplish this. And then use ToList() or FirstOrDefault to run the query against entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access the DbContext from any given entity. An entity is supposed to be treated as a "Plain Old CLR Object" (POCO), with no relation whatsoever to Entity Framework components as far as the compiler is concerned.

Depending on *why* you want access to unrelated tables when handling entities, different solutions exist. Dependency injection, repository pattern, whatever you want.